# Extend existing XML by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to extend an existing XML file and add a new node. I'm loading the XML containing a lot of products, add a new one and save it.

I'm using Nokogiri and Ruby 1.9.3.

This is the best that I created:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
  root do
    load_xml = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read("test.xml"))
    parent.add_child(load_xml.root)
    data do
      name "Name"
    end
  end
end

file = File.open("test.xml",'w')
file.puts builder.to_xml
file.close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nokogiri::XML::Builder` is actually only used when creating new XML-Files, not when editing them.

Also your code loads the XML and puts it into a new root-Node (root) while it appends a new child (the data-node) to it. Is this really the desired behaviour?

Normally you would do adding a node like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read("test.xml"))
name_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("name",doc)
name_node.content = "Name"
data_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("data",doc)
data_node.add_child(name_node)
doc.root.add_child(data_node)

file = File.open("test.xml",'w')
file.puts doc.to_xml
file.close
```

This is without creating a new root node, because this seems a little bit
peculiar to me...

Also you might want to try the [Nokogiri-Documentation](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html), it is fairly extensive.

There are other ways, which would use `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` to create everything downside from and including *data*, this would be an example for this combined approach:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
  data do 
    name "Name"
  end
end
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read("test.xml"))
doc.root.add_child builder.doc.root

file = File.open("test.xml",'w')
file.puts doc.to_xml
file.close
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. That's exactly what I need and I tried to do. That's much better example then official nokogiri tutorials.
Thank you again :)